# iOS: in-house app wireless installation does not display progress

Tags: ios, ios9

I am using the procedure described here http://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apda0e3426d7 to install an in-house app using a wireless network. As indicated in the docs, I have created a website serving a webpage containing the link to the app manifest.

A user would typically install the in-house app on his device by opening the webpage and then pressing on the link to the manifest. With iOS 7.x, the Safari browser would then go in the background and the user would see the app installation in progress (app logo + progress indicator on top of the logo).

In iOS 9.x this is no longer the case: Safari does not go in the background and there is no visible indication of the app installation except a very tiny progress indicator at the upper left corner of the device's screen. In other words there is no immediate visual clue that the app is installing, as in iOS 6.x & 7.x

However the installation completes successfully and the app logo eventually appears on the device screen.

Is there a specific way of activating the previous iOS 6.x & 7.x behaviour? Has something changed in the in-house wireless installation procedure?

Thanks

Comment: I see the same behaviour. In my case it is not consistent. Sometimes I see progress indicator and sometimes I do not (mostly not).

Comment: @everyday productive Yes same for me. Progress indicator displayed sporadically. I am surprised no one else has filed an issue for this. Don't want to burn one of my support tokens for this either...

Comment: ;). Indeed. I will still observe it for a while and see if this gets fixed in the any future release. It was still good to know that I am not the only one noticing this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in my company, and it's more a bug than a feature. I hope the 9.3 version will fix this

Comment: if this is really a bug and not a config problem, this has not worked since iOS 8.x. Is there an official way of filing a bug to Apple?

Comment: Yes : https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login.html?appIdKey=77e2a60d4bdfa6b7311c854a56505800be3c24e3a27a670098ff61b69fc5214b&sslEnabled=true&rv=3